# AudioContext failed to resume in iOS Safari 17.4 beta: InvalidStateError: Failed to start the audio device

Tags: safari, ios17, audiocontext

The problem is new in the newly published iOS Safari 17.4 beta.

The code below will go into the catch block with error message:

> InvalidStateError: Failed to start the audio device

Tested on an iPhone 11 with iOS 17.4 beta.

```js
const context = new AudioContext();

window.handleClick = () => {
  console.log('state', context.state);
  context.resume().then(() => {
      document.write('state:' + context.state);
      console.log('state', context.state);
  }, (e) => {
      document.write('state:' + context.state + ' ' + e);
      console.error(e);
  });
};
```

Live demo click [here](https://ios17-4-audio-context-resume-bug.glitch.me/)

Comment: Is it fixed with newest betas? https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/1ahctly/comment/kpb3p5m